# Illustrator: Change spacing between objects in Grid

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Is there a way of re-spacing multiple objects arranged in a grid?

From:

[image]

To:

[image]

I already tried to ungroup all elements, enlarge the artboard and use "distribute horizontally" and "distribute vertically", but it turned out:

[really weird (no image, not enough reputation on graphicdesign for 3 links)]

Any help it greatly appreciated!
Sorry, if this is a duplicate, I did my best, searching for an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the last column and move it out, then use horizontal distributing. Then move the last row down the same amount, and use vertical distributing.

[image]

Comment: Just noticed the logic behind it, many thanks @paulshryock